# preserve zebra striping with jquery tablesorter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The table on [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/list) is sorted by the [tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). The candy-striping is not re-applied after sorting, so the shaded and unshaded rows appear in the wrong sequence after a sort is performed. Click on the Name column to see an example of this.

Is there a way to redo the striping after a sort?

Comment: You think about using CSS odd/even rules and not have to worry about it. [well at least for browsers that support it.]

Comment: I didn't know there are CSS odd/even rules, CSS3, I guess?

Comment: `.tablesorter tr:nth-child(even)` will select the even rows of a table and `.tablesorter tr:nth-child(odd)` will select the odd rows: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the zebra widget. Use the following piece of code to initialize the `tablesorter`:

```
$("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra']
});
```

`Zebra` is the only widget included by default. [See here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-widgets.html) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I've also found that you can solve this problem like this:

```
$('your_table').tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    widgetZebra: { css: ['normal-row', 'alt-row' ] }
});
```

Found here:  http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html

In my case, just initializing the zebra widget would not actually apply the table striping, even though I had the CSS classes .even and .odd defined (which I believe are the default classes that the zebra widget assigns).